# install_target error 71 (ignored) qt for android

Tags: android, qt

I started development and building with Qt for Android, and one problem made me spent some time is when trying to run a simple HelloWorld program, when building, Qt complains saying:

**[install_target] error 71 (ignored)**

Well, even though there are some resources in Qt forums, and even if I read them till today I didnt understand the problem.

Basically it happens because you CANNOT USE WHITESPACES IN THE PROJECT PATH.

I decided to add this wiki answer to make it more accessible for future users.

Comment: You might want to consider making this a question to fit with SO's Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

As explain before,

**YOU CANNOT USE WHITESPACES IN THE PROJECT PATH.**